# Self-inhibitions are diagonal matrix

Tags: differential-equations

In all the discontinuous neural networks models, the self-inhibitions are diagonal matrix,  what is the reason for this assumption?

Comment: Please see the FAQ http://mathoverflow.net/faq. I suspect this is off-topic for this site. http://math.stackexchange.com should be able to help you as long as you make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

A neural network models a "charge" going through different objects (such as concepts or phonemes) by means of a graph where the nodes represent the objects, edges represent the connections (possible paths) and the edge-widths of an edge between A and B represent the probability or percentage of a "charge" that goes from A to B.

In the incidence matrix that represents a neural network, all the entries in column A describe where the charge from location A goes to. When you want to model the fact that some charge stays with A until the next time step, this means you want A "to send this charge to itself" (i.e. hold it). Since each row of the incidence matrix represents the receiver of the charge, you want the charge A is "holding" to be sent and received by itself. So the entry where A is the sender and the receiver is that entry in A's column that is on the diagonal of the matrix. Thus any self-interactions are characterized by the diagonal entries of the Neural Network's incidence matrix.